# API Pagination,Filtering,Sorting VS CLIENT Pagination,Filtering,Sorting

Tags: node.js, database, rest, api, pagination

**Scenario**

- A web site page has a table view with Pagination,Filtering,Sorting.
- The data in table is acquired from a REST API server and the data contain
  millions of records.
- DataBase <---> REST API Server <---> Web Sever <---> Browser

---

**Issue**

- where would be the best place to do Pagination,Filtering,Sorting.

---

**Possible Solutions**

- Paginate,Filter,Sort in **web Server**

  - REST API Server send complete list ( which the requested entity may not need)
  - web server has to Paginate,Filter,Sort with logic may increase load
  - if web server just wants only record REST API server need to have seperate api for that else web server has to parse from complete list
- Paginate,Filter,Sort in **REST API server**

  - REST API server takes input arguments and do Pagination,Filtering,Sorting
  - web server can directly bind it to table view without formatting result
  - only requested data is sent so bandwidth is saved
  - more like Google's fusion tables api

---

What will be the best way to do this without violating REST API standards ?

Answer (score 0):

/* Handles the pagination. */
router.post('/products/view-front', function(req, res){

```
/* Set our internal DB variable */
var db = req.db;

    /* Set our collection */
    products = db.get('products');

    pag_content = '';
    pag_navigation = '';

    page = parseInt(req.body.data.page); /* Page we are currently at */
    name = req.body.data.name; /* Name of the column name we want to sort */
    sort = req.body.data.sort == 'ASC' ? 1 : -1; /* Order of our sort (DESC or ASC) */
    max = parseInt(req.body.data.max); /* Number of items to display per page */
    search = req.body.data.search; /* Keyword provided on our search box */

    cur_page = page;
    page -= 1;
    per_page = max ? max : 20;
    previous_btn = true;
    next_btn = true;
    first_btn = true;
    last_btn = true;
    start = page * per_page;

    where_search = {};

/* Check if there is a string inputted on the search box */
if( search != '' ){
    /* If a string is inputted, include an additional query logic to our main query to filter the results */
    var filter = new RegExp(search, 'i');
    where_search = {
        '$or' : [
            {'name' : filter},
            {'price' : filter},
        ]
    }
}

var all_items = '';
var count = '';
var sort_query = {};

/* We use async task to make sure we only return data when all queries completed successfully */
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        /* Use name and sort variables as field names */
        sort_query[name] = sort;

        /* Retrieve all the posts */
        products.find( where_search, {
            limit: per_page,
            skip: start,
            sort: sort_query

        }, function(err, docs){
            if (err) throw err;
            // console.log(docs);
            all_items = docs;
            callback();

        });
    },
    function(callback) {
        products.count(where_search, function(err, doc_count){
            if (err) throw err;
            // console.log(count);
            count = doc_count;
            callback();
        });
    }
], function(err) { //This is the final callback
    /* Check if our query returns anything. */
    if( count ){
        for (var key in all_items) {
            pag_content += '<div class="col-sm-3">' +
                '<div class="panel panel-default">' +
                    '<div class="panel-heading">' +
                        all_items[key].name +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="panel-body p-0 p-b">' +
                        '<a href="products-single.php?item=' + all_items[key]._id + '"><img src="img/uploads/' + all_items[key].featured_image + '" width="100%" class="img-responsive" /></a>' +
                        '<div class="list-group m-0">' +
                            '<div class="list-group-item b-0 b-t">' +
                                '<i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-2x pull-left ml-r"></i>' +
                                '<p class="list-group-item-text">Price</p>' +
                                '<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">$' + parseFloat(all_items[key].price).toFixed(2) + '</h4>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="list-group-item b-0 b-t">' +
                                '<i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x pull-left ml-r"></i>' +
                                '<p class="list-group-item-text">Quantity</p>' +
                                '<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">' + all_items[key].quantity + '</h4>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="panel-footer">' +
                        '</p><a href="products-single.php?item=' + all_items[key]._id + '" class="btn btn-success btn-block">View Item</a></p>' +
                     '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        }
    }

    pag_content = pag_content + "<br class = 'clear' />";

    no_of_paginations = Math.ceil(count / per_page);

    if (cur_page >= 7) {
        start_loop = cur_page - 3;
        if (no_of_paginations > cur_page + 3)
            end_loop = cur_page + 3;
        else if (cur_page <= no_of_paginations && cur_page > no_of_paginations - 6) {
            start_loop = no_of_paginations - 6;
            end_loop = no_of_paginations;
        } else {
            end_loop = no_of_paginations;
        }
    } else {
        start_loop = 1;
        if (no_of_paginations > 7)
            end_loop = 7;
        else
            end_loop = no_of_paginations;
    }

    pag_navigation += "<ul>";

    if (first_btn && cur_page > 1) {
        pag_navigation += "<li p='1' class='active'>First</li>";
    } else if (first_btn) {
        pag_navigation += "<li p='1' class='inactive'>First</li>";
    }

    if (previous_btn && cur_page > 1) {
        pre = cur_page - 1;
        pag_navigation += "<li p='" + pre + "' class='active'>Previous</li>";
    } else if (previous_btn) {
        pag_navigation += "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
    }
    for (i = start_loop; i <= end_loop; i++) {

        if (cur_page == i)
            pag_navigation += "<li p='" + i + "' class = 'selected' >" + i + "</li>";
        else
            pag_navigation += "<li p='" + i + "' class='active'>" + i + "</li>";
    }

    if (next_btn && cur_page < no_of_paginations) {
        nex = cur_page + 1;
        pag_navigation += "<li p='" + nex + "' class='active'>Next</li>";
    } else if (next_btn) {
        pag_navigation += "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
    }

    if (last_btn && cur_page < no_of_paginations) {
        pag_navigation += "<li p='" + no_of_paginations + "' class='active'>Last</li>";
    } else if (last_btn) {
        pag_navigation += "<li p='" + no_of_paginations + "' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
    }

    pag_navigation = pag_navigation + "</ul>";

    var response = {
        'content': pag_content,
        'navigation' : pag_navigation
    };

    res.send(response);

});
```

});

module.exports = router;